# How do I use nginx with Go for a subdomain?

Tags: nginx, go

I have a simple go program that uses http.ListenAndServe to serve content. I use nginx to serve multiple applications on one server, and I want to use it for the go program too. I've tried looking for information on it, but all I found people using FastCGI or node.js to get it to work. Is it possible to do it with just pure Go and nginx? I understand how to use nginx with a subdomain, but not a Go program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can connect Nginx to your Go program directly via proxy_pass.
Given:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

You just need to add to your nginx configuration the proxy_pass:

```
location @go {
    proxy_pass            127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```